# Previously defined variable in bash script not expanded when I try to execute a command through SSH

Tags: android, linux, bash, ssh, termux

```bash
#!/bin/bash
CLIP=$(termux-clipboard-get)
ssh user@ip 'cat>~/Scripts/clip.log<<<$CLIP'
```

This is a very basic bash script to forward my system clipboard from my phone (through termux) into a file on my desktop through SSH.

The issue is the third line, I can't get it to write what's stored in the variable and it ends up writing nothing.

I've tested:

- `echo $CLIP`, and the clipboard request works.
- replacing `$CLIP` with a string, and `clip.log` updates properly.

Comment: Because of the single quotes, the variable gets expanded on the remote side.

Comment: @user1934428 This is true, but it implies an incomplete fix: just switching to double quotes is still bad practice -- you don't want any of your double-quoted content to expand into something that runs a shell injection attack when ssh passes it to a remote shell.

Comment: For example, let's say that your clipboard contained `hi; rm -rf ~` -- you don't want `cat>~/Scripts/clip.log<<<hi; rm -rf ~` getting run. There are plenty of more complicated examples available that work around trivial attempts at quoting &c as well. `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` is an example I often give; the first `rm` runs when injected into a string either unquoted or in double quotes, the second one runs when injected into a string surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : It was not meant as a fix, but as an explanation, for why the variable expands empty on the target host. One solution which comes to my mind would be to use the ability of ssh to transfer certain selected environment variables to the target, but I see now that the answer given by Stephen Ostermiller is much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

It would work better if you used a pipe rather than a variable.  Then you don't need to worry as much about escaping or quotes.

```bash
termux-clipboard-get | ssh user@ip 'cat > ~/Scripts/clip.log'
```

If you want it to append to the log file, you could use `>>` rather than `>`.